# Research-assistant classification in C.V

Tags: cv, research-assistantship

I was a research assistant at a university when I had a master’s degree. Now I got a Ph.D from a different university. I want to apply for a faculty position.

In which of the following CV categories can being a research assistant be considered:

- Work Experience
- Training Course
- Qualifications and Certificates

Needless to say, I have a report letter from the head of department, where I was a research assistant.

Comment: Is being a research assistant not a job where you are from? Why would it not be work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that among your option, Work Experience is probably best. I doubt that you were given a formal "Certificate" for your work. A letter isn't the same thing. It is probably more easily evaluated as work experience in any case. The letter will stand for itself. Don't embellish it.